# New to Kimono, having problems editing an API

Tags: kimono

I'm looking for an easy to use but fast web scraping tool. I recently started experimenting with Kimono after the acquisition of Kimono and transition to a desktp app. I got stuck when I tried to go back and edit and finish my API. I tried to follow the instructions in the help menu. I opened the desktop app, opened my API then clicked on the [Edit] button. It switched to my browser and opened up the target URL. But I got nothing from Kimono - no menu bar. I'm  not sure if the extension is supposed to open automatically, but it gave me no hint what I was supposed to do next, so I opened the chrome extension. There are no "properties" (or what I would usually call fields or table columns). I don't know how to open the existing API in chrome. Disclosure: I opened a thread prevviously and got some good advice, but I got stuck again and didn't get any further response.  I'd reallly appreciate any advice you all can give me.